# Como eliminar una relación en laravel

Tags: laravel, relaciones

tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
    Schema::create('location_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('location_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('category_name');
        $table->boolean('primary_category');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

y también tengo la clase llamada Location la cual tiene la función `categories`

```
    public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'location_category', 'location_id', 'category_id')
        ->withPivot('category_name', 'primary_category')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

quiero eliminar DATOS de categories y también de Locations, planeaba hacer esto

```
        $locationToDelete = Location::where('name', $location['name']);
        $locationToDelete->categories()->delete();
        $locationToDelete->delete();
```

pero he leído en algún sitio que si hago eso en una clase que tenga hasMany / belongsToMany eliminaré la referencia y no la relación.

Es correcto lo que estoy haciendo? Cómo puedo eliminar la location_categories y Location también?

**EDIT:**
los ID de mi tabla Location están sujetos a cambios debido una sincronización ajena a mí donde no se mantienen fijos, así que los identificamos a través de $location['name'], no hay ningún problema con esto, pero...

¿es válido hacer esto?

```
        $locationToDelete = Location::where('name', $location['name']);
        Category::where('location_id', $locationToDelete->id)->delete();
        $locationToDelete->delete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De tu pregunta se extrae que necesitas eliminar:

- Los datos de categories y locations (específicos)
- Además eliminar también la relación que se grabó en la tabla intermedia la cual es: `location_category` de esos 2 objetos

Dado lo anterior, considero que se debe conseguir en 3 pasos:

- Obtienes y asignas en variables cada location y category que deseas eliminar
- Usas el id de dichos objetos para proceder con la eliminación de la relación de la tabla intermedia por medio de detach
- Finalmente eliminas los objetos

De tal modo que puede ser así:

```
$locationToDelete = Location::where('columna', $valor)->first();

$categoryToDelete = Category::where('columna', $valor)->first();

$locationToDelete->categories()->detach([$locationToDelete->id, $categoryToDelete->id]);

$locationToDelete->delete();

$categoryToDelete->delete();
```

Hacemos uso de la eliminación individual de los objetos, ya que el método [`detach`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching) solo elimina las claves de la tabla intermedia pero los modelos prevalecen en la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias, sin embargo los ID de mi tabla Location están sujetos a una sincronización donde no se mantienen fijos, así que los identificamos a través de $location['name'].  (continua)

Comment: he actualizado la pregunta con un código al final para ver si es válido lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: Podría obtener el ID con $locationToDelete = Location::where('name', $location['name']); y luego solicitarlo una línea más abajo con $locationToDelete->id, ya que está dentro de la misma función no habría problema con un posible cambio de ID repentino

Comment: En el caso de los objetos de location y category su busca por una columna alterna al id, donde si empleo las pk es en el método detach pues son los valores que se requieren para proceder con la eliminación de los mismos en la tabla intermedia, ahora respecto a tu edición donde preguntas si es correcto: te diría que no pues no veo por que accedes `location_id` desde el modelo Category cuando según lo expuesto en tu pregunta esa es una fk en la tabla intermedia. En cualquier caso si esta respuesta no satisface del todo la necesidad planteada invito a esperar que otras personas aporten